# How to set android:layout_column programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

How can i set `android:layout_column` programmatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for e.g. you have TextView then do this way

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this); 
tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(1));
```

Comment: you save my life